# Jolt Transformation: Make the nested object field to be part of main Json Object and also convert the nested object to String

Tags: arrays, json, transformation, jolt

I am new to JOLT transformation, can someone help me in transforming the Input JSON to the desired output?

**Input JSON:**

```json
[
  {
    "product_id": 1,
    "product_description": "Product 1 details",
    "billing_details": {
      "product_id": 1,
      "billing_description": "Product 1 billing  Details"
    },
    "product_part_desc": {
      "id": 1,
      "part_description": "product 1 part description"
    }
  },
  {
    "product_id": 2,
    "product_description": "Product 2 details",
    "billing_details": {
      "product_id": 1,
      "billing_description": "Product 2 billing  Details"
    },
    "product_part_desc": {
      "id": 1,
      "part_description": "product 2 part description"
    }
  }
]
```

**Tried Specification:**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "product_id": "[&1].id",
        "product_description": "[&1].description",
        "billing_details": {
          "billing_description": "[&2].bill_desc"
        },
        "*": "&"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "product_part_desc": "=toString(@(1,product_part_desc))"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Expected output:**

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "product_description": "Product 1 details",
    "billing_description": "Product 1 billing  Details",
    "product_part_desc": "{id=1, part_description=product 1 part description}"
  },
  {
    "product_id": 2,
    "product_description": "Product 2 details",
    "billing_description": "Product 2 billing  Details",
    "product_part_desc": "{id=1, part_description=product 2 part description}"
  }
]
```

But the above spec is giving the below output
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

- a **concat** function within a **modify** spec in order to get
  **`product_part_desc`** attribute
- a **`@billing_details.billing_description`** identifier along with a **shift** transformation spec to get
  **`billing_description`** attribute

as result:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "product_part_desc": "=concat('',@0)"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*id": "[&1].id",
        "p*": "[&1].&",
        "@billing_details.billing_description": "[&1].billing_description"
      }
    }
  },
  {// this spec is added only to sort the attributes as desired
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "id": "[&1].&",
        "product_description": "[&1].&",
        "billing_description": "[&1].&",
        "product_part_desc": "[&1].&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "product_id": "[&1].id",
        "product_description": "[&1].description",
        "billing_details": {
          "billing_description": "[&2].bill_desc"
        },
        "product_part_desc": {
          "*": "[&2].product_part_desc"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "product_part_desc": "=join(', part_description=',@0)",
        "product_part_des*": "=concat('{id=',@0,'}')"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

You can change the keys as you want in the above code.